# Some Cassandra nodes have less data when compared to other nodes

Tags: cassandra

We have a 2 DC setup with following software configuration

- Cassandra 3.3  - Windows
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Java8

Following is the nodetool status of the cluster.

```
Datacenter: DC1
================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  xx.xxx.130.156  43.33 GB   256          ?       5a37db21-0f86-4969-b0e2-7721c3440f89  Rack4
UN  xx.xxx.130.27   13.12 GB   256          ?       3faf86a6-ec98-489f-a25e-f03f0fd24dda  Rack1
UN  xx.xxx.132.27   26.12 GB   256          ?       5ddf9507-edfe-4056-b5dc-89d6071c7c49  Rack5
UN  xx.xxx.129.250  60.83 GB   256          ?       c5828b34-fe06-4ad5-ba41-1e16ae68643f  Rack0
UN  xx.xxx.130.122  24.26 GB   256          ?       7630c0ca-c842-4f35-98d8-f0dd80075cd9  Rack3
UN  xx.xxx.130.26   42.71 GB   256          ?       1da60f12-ae94-4f2d-9ee7-cfa9475d7de6  Rack1
**UN  xx.xxx.130.153  10.62 MB   256          ?       7b7d3174-83a8-46dd-96f0-a49561d3a5db  Rack4**
UN  xx.xxx.130.56   30.75 GB   256          ?       07735b9a-bba4-4c48-b910-6fe0bb66d915  Rack1
UN  xx.xxx.130.22   36.51 GB   256          ?       9c3aaa45-f6ed-4150-b2be-07b77247213a  Rack0
UN  xx.xxx.132.21   52.12 GB   256          ?       504e95e5-4cbc-4865-90f5-43a140d7eb37  Rack5
**UN  xx.xxx.130.20   7.61 MB    256          ?       873567f4-89af-475c-b396-46d748244831  Rack0**
UN  xx.xxx.130.115  22.38 GB   256          ?       5a3fb240-4ae3-411f-8f77-62a5d686c792  Rack3
UN  xx.xxx.130.18   26.24 GB   256          ?       53112ffb-88bb-4764-8fcf-50ae4f7b2b0d  Rack0
UN  xx.xxx.135.208  40.17 GB   256          ?       9147c4d4-0e4f-49ef-a543-f5551cf5d708  Rack3
UN  xx.xxx.130.76   22.05 GB   256          ?       47eaff85-43cf-4cdd-a190-f0f2ad20f2c0  Rack2
UN  xx.xxx.135.202  35.53 GB   256          ?       5b1d8b78-142e-4a2f-a25e-712ea83dc99d  Rack2
UN  xx.xxx.130.103  24.37 GB   256          ?       57e555b1-d699-484f-b614-425bb2ea9303  Rack3
UN  xx.xxx.135.198  23.47 GB   256          ?       b6df9353-36cc-49e5-acf8-d00ff05d2036  Rack2
UN  xx.xxx.135.197  21 GB      256          ?       06fc2ded-ca0d-4cb7-89eb-4cfdd40b078b  Rack2
**UN  xx.xxx.135.165  35.41 MB   256          ?       b8f33626-c02e-41c3-ab07-e44b9e24b386  Rack1**
UN  xx.xxx.130.163  43.47 GB   256          ?       d543ad18-48cc-498e-a3bc-d21323645922  Rack4
UN  xx.xxx.131.0    57.67 GB   256          ?       973c5fcd-9a3e-44c2-b94b-7f5cb557ceef  Rack5
Datacenter: DC2
================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  xx.xxx.171.30   73.24 GB   256          ?       876eba21-3769-4e63-bddf-971a2bb77a51  Rack0
UN  xx.xxx.168.94   68.69 GB   256          ?       3de8312d-1fa6-4c92-b76a-f7b999196cdb  Rack3
UN  xx.xxx.164.60   74.81 GB   256          ?       856f82a3-00ff-4d36-a2b4-9b19f47cf789  Rack0
UN  xx.xxx.172.153  69.17 GB   256          ?       6b07b00e-69f2-41b7-b52e-a43cde49db67  Rack4
UN  xx.xxx.166.248  75.48 GB   256          ?       ca5a00df-7b37-453c-9a52-498042981640  Rack2
UN  xx.xxx.169.56   73.69 GB   256          ?       15e9f6c9-edff-49c3-a5fb-838300940ecf  Rack4
UN  xx.xxx.168.245  74.42 GB   256          ?       ffb0de64-ffcd-43e2-bc2d-0a2f5b9dcb82  Rack3
UN  xx.xxx.164.243  67.84 GB   256          ?       90b3f44a-b48e-4503-abaa-abed6ebaf00d  Rack1
UN  xx.xxx.164.207  80.62 GB   256          ?       d441482d-c4e6-4ae9-ae52-058231055fb5  Rack1
UN  xx.xxx.167.239  69.86 GB   256          ?       50ffe4ca-1f93-48c0-904f-7e5201661531  Rack2
UN  xx.xxx.166.14   70.67 GB   256          ?       610f7ac0-f297-4929-8fd0-c0b59532cac4  Rack2
UN  xx.xxx.164.106  67.71 GB   256          ?       fae8b23f-6717-4e1f-bf01-23f9fded3856  Rack1
UN  xx.xxx.168.199  72.79 GB   256          ?       7ec1b98f-5266-4d8f-bc9d-acb9f93f8ef0  Rack3
UN  xx.xxx.169.99   73.54 GB   256          ?       81e23c04-bf82-4a22-aa2f-3e5295b96f9f  Rack4
UN  xx.xxx.164.32   68.01 GB   256          ?       d4796c1c-c60d-4201-89bb-180381764df9  Rack0
```

We noticed that data size on some of the nodes in DC1 data center is in MB while others are in GB. I tried decommissioning these nodes and join then again, but it did not resolve the issue.

What could be the reason and how to trouble shoot the issue. Would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Try running "nodetool status <keyspace name>" so that it will show what percentage of the keyspace each node owns.  If the small nodes have about the same percent owned as the others, I'd suspect these nodes joined the cluster after the data was inserted. If that's the case, you can populate them with the data they own by running "nodetool rebuild" on them.

Comment: Thanks Jim. Percentage of keyspace were the same as other nodes. so based on your recommendation I ran 'rebuild'. Now I see all the nodes where data was in MB, now has comparable data. Few things I did not understand... I did try decommissioning the node, delete all the data directories and start the node. As part of bootstrap process, node should have got all the data. Also, we run 'nodetool repair' whenever node goes down and comes back. It should have fixed at that time as well... I though rebuild is for bringing up new datacenters. That's why I did not try that command

Comment: Glad that helped. I copied my comment as an answer if you want to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running "nodetool status " so that it will show what percentage of the keyspace each node owns. If the small nodes have about the same percent owned as the others, I'd suspect these nodes joined the cluster after the data was inserted. If that's the case, you can populate them with the data they own by running "nodetool rebuild" on them.

When a node is missing most of its data, I find it's faster and more efficient to use rebuild than repair. That's why I suggested it in your situation. The repair operation seems better suited to fixing small amounts of missing data, while rebuild just streams everything the node should have in bulk and reprocesses it. This may result in the node temporarily having some redundant data, but it will be cleaned up by compaction.

I'm not sure why your nodes didn't stream the data during bootstrap, unless you have them marked as seed nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your repair did not complete for all ranges.  The size of your data makes me suggest you run nodetool repair -pr on the nodes that did not seem like owning their fair share of data, with a small range of tokens (options -st ... -et ...). Nodetool ring will produce tokens by node.  Also, depending on your schema it could help running repair by keyspace and even table.